How to detect mock location in android API below 31 since isMockProvider() is deprecated?
I'm developing an Android app where I need to detect whether the location is real or coming from a mock provider.
I found that Android provides the Location.isFromMockProvider() method for this purpose. However, I noticed that this method is deprecated, and the recommended replacement is Location.isMock(), which is only available on API 31+.
While isFromMockProvider() works fine on devices running API 31 or higher (it works because it calls isMock), I'm facing an issue when running it on devices with API levels lower than 31. It always returns false, even though I'm using a fake GPS app to mock the location.
Is there a reliable way to detect mock locations on devices below API level 31, or any workaround for this issue? I'd appreciate any guidance on how to handle this across different Android versions.
isMockProvider

isMock

